# No matching sls found for 'swapfile' in env 'base'

Tags: salt-stack

I have successfully been using saltstack for managing virtual and bare-metal Ubuntu-14.04-servers for about a year.

On master, I have the following /srv/salt/top.sls:

```
base:
  '*':
    - common                   
    - users
    - openvpn  # openvpn-formula    
    - openvpn.config # openvpn-formula 
    - fail2ban # fail2ban-formula   
    - fail2ban.config # fail2ban-formula
    - swapfile  # swapfile-formula  
    - ntp # ntp-formula to set up and configure the ntp client or serv
```

In /etc/salt/master I have included the following:

```
gitfs_remotes:
    - https://github.com/srbolle/openvpn-formula.git
    - https://github.com/srbolle/postgres-formula.git
    - https://github.com/srbolle/fail2ban-formula.git
    - https://github.com/srbolle/ntp-formula.git
    - https://github.com/srbolle/swapfile-formula.git
```

I have had no problems with saltstack-formulas until now, but when I recently included the "swapfile-formula" I get the following when running

```
salt '*' state.highstate:


servername:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    No matching sls found for 'swapfile' in env 'base'
```

Also, I get the same error message when running:

```
salt 'servername' state.show_sls swapfile
servername:
    - No matching sls found for 'swapfile' in env 'base'
```

When I run:

```
salt servername state.show_top
```

'swapfile' is listed. I have tried to clear the cache, restarted servers, recreated servers, used 'kwalify -m top.sls' to validate my top.sls-file. I have spent days on this error, and don't know how to further debug (logs don't show anything suspiciuos).

Thankful for any clues on how to proceed.

Comment: Have a look at the masters logfile `/var/log/salt/master` (on debian like distros). If the master has problems with the gitfs for this formula, you should find them.

Comment: any clues in the log?

Comment: dahrens: thanks for reaching out. There is nothing new in /var/log/salt/master. I just ran the highstate command with the same error message in terminal as mentioned above, but the last message in the log-file is 6 days ago. I should mention that I am running this on vagrant virtual servers.

Comment: check out `/var/cache/salt/gitfs` - check the map file to see which SHA1 belongs to your `swapfile-formula` - check the contents for things that may cause your issue. e.g. does the repository folder contains the swapfile folder. As you use vagrant - have you already tried to reproduce the error in a fresh box?

Comment: Thanks again dahrens. Yes, I have tried with fresh vagrant boxes, with the same results. And yes, the /var/cache/salt/master/gitfs contains the swapfile folder. So far, I have not been able to find anything unusual in this folder.